# Google Map Visual WebPart

Tags: development, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, javascript

Some that has an guide on have to create an Visual WebPart using Google Maps for an list....

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    string rScript = "";
    rScript += "<script src=\"http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&key=" + 
               m_rGoogleKey + "\"\n type=\"text/javascript\"></script>\n";
    rScript += "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n";
    rScript += "//<![CDATA[\n";
    rScript += "function Init()\n";
    rScript += "{\n";
    rScript += "var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById(\"map\"));\n";
    if (DisableDragging)
        rScript += "map.disableDragging();\n";
    rScript += "var latlng = new GLatLng(" + m_dLatitude + ", " + m_dLongitude + ");\n";
    rScript += "map.setCenter(latlng, " + m_nZoomLevel + ");\n";
    if (DisplayZoomControl)
        rScript += "map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());\n";
    rScript += "map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());\n";
    rScript += "var mkr = new GMarker(latlng);\n";
    if (DisplayIcon)
        rScript += "map.addOverlay(mkr);\n";
    rScript += "}\n";
    rScript += "//]]>\n";
    rScript += "</script>\n";
    rScript += " <div id=\"map\" style=\"width: " + GWidth + "px; height: " + 
               GHeight + "px\"></div>\n";
    writer.Write(rScript);
    if (!Page.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("MapInit"))
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(string), "MapInit",
                  "Init()", true);
}
```

Comment: Hi Morski, Welcome to SharePoint StackExchange. Your question isn't very clear, so I was wondering if you could add more details by editing the question? I have taken the liberty of editing the question to reformat the code for you. Also please refer to the [FAQ][1] for a guide on how to use this Q&A site. [1]: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: Hi my friend , my question is like this  0 down vote favorite
 

Some that has an guide on have to create an Visual WebPart using Google Maps for an list....

Comment: Bye the way welcome by your self...

Answer (score 1):

Morski,

There are some web parts available Open Source, you can use them: 
[1- SharePoint 2010 Google Maps V3 WebPart](http://spgooglemappart.codeplex.com/)
[2- Display Google Maps in a Sharepoint Web Part using a Sharepoint List](http://googlemapswebpart.codeplex.com/)
[3- SharePoint 2010 Google Maps Web Part for Sandbox and Farm Solutions](http://sp2010googlemaps.codeplex.com/)
[4- sharepoint-google-maps-webpart](http://code.google.com/p/sharepoint-google-maps-webpart/)